# How to modify lock object in a subversion pre-lock or post-lock hook

Tags: svn, locking, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

Is it at all possible to modify a lock in a subversion server using a pre-lock or post-lock hook? Specifically, I'd like to extend the cryptic lock-owner string (my company chose to use ids rather than real names and we are using VisualSVNServer with integrated windows authentication) and possibly set an expiry date for the lock.

I'd even settle for a workaround like rejecting the original lock and creating a new one instead, reusing the original lock-token (that would be required to avoid breaking the link with the working copy, right?).

I have studied the svn book for svn 1.7 and googled until my fingers bled but got less than nothing on this topic.